# Sliding a single thumbnail in Bootstrap 3

Tags: slider, twitter-bootstrap-3, thumbnails

I am making a bootstrap 3 thumbnail slider, it looks like below.

```
<div id="homeSlider" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        //indicators
    </ol>

    <section class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                //thumbnail
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                //thumbnail
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                //thumbnail
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                //thumbnail
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                //thumbnail
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                //thumbnail
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                //thumbnail
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                //thumbnail
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    //Carousal Controls
</div>
```

The twist is that i need to slide a single thumbnail at a time not the whole set of 4 thumbnails.
Looking forward for help !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slide one item at a time and not all 4 thumbs, all you have to do is to use the [default carousel code](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) and you will have one thumbnail/item and not 4 like it is in your example

```
<section class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        //thumbnail     
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        //thumbnail
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    <div class="item">
        //thumbnail
    </div>
</section>
```